# I'm having trouble installing Flask-Ask on a Windows 10 PC

Tags: python, windows, flask-ask

I am getting the following output when I try to install Flask-Ask on my Windows 10 PC.

I have searched for solutions, but nothing has helped so far.

Thanks for any help.

```
$ pip install Flask-Ask
Collecting Flask-Ask
  Using cached Flask-Ask-0.9.8.tar.gz (40 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\william miller\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\William Miller\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-0uhvx_b_\\flask-ask_fb3af15f962c434ca23e3fa0eaa93e8e\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\William Miller\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-0uhvx_b_\\flask-ask_fb3af15f962c434ca23e3fa0eaa93e8e\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\William Miller\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-89xq1ph5'
         cwd: C:\Users\William Miller\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-0uhvx_b_\flask-ask_fb3af15f962c434ca23e3fa0eaa93e8e\
    Complete output (5 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\William Miller\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-0uhvx_b_\flask-ask_fb3af15f962c434ca23e3fa0eaa93e8e\setup.py", line 8, in <module>
        from pip.req import parse_requirements
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip.req'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.

$ python --version
Python 3.9.0
$ pip --version
pip 20.3.3 from c:\users\william miller\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.9)
```

Answer (score 0):

try to update your pip:

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

and then :

```
pip install Flask-Ask
```

Comment: I upgraded pip, no help

Comment: pip install -U pip-tools

Try this one

Comment: Thanks but no help with pip install -U pip-tools